# How to get shortest XML subtree with current node?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have something like:

```
<XML>
    <LEVEL1A>
        <LEVEL2AA>
            <LEVEL3AAA>Some textAAA</LEVEL3AAA>
        </LEVEL2AA>
        <LEVEL2AB>Some textAB</LEVEL2AB>
    </LEVEL1A>
    <LEVEL1B>
        <LEVEL2BA>Some textBA</LEVEL2BA>
    </LEVEL1B>
    <LEVEL1C>
        <LEVEL2CA>
            <LEVEL3CAA>Some textCAA</LEVEL3CAA>
            <LEVEL3CAB>Some textCAB</LEVEL3CAB>
        </LEVEL2CA>
        <LEVEL2CB>Some textCB</LEVEL2CB>
        <LEVEL2CC>Some textCC</LEVEL2CC>
    </LEVEL1C>
</XML>
```

And if I need to get all parents as XML-tree of node `//XML/LEVEL1C/LEVEL2CA/LEVEL3CAB`, then result should be receive:

```
<XML>
    <LEVEL1C>
        <LEVEL2CA>
            <LEVEL3CAB>Some textCAB</LEVEL3CAB>
        </LEVEL2CA>
    </LEVEL1C>
</XML>
```

So, I don't need to just get parents names, but I need entire subtree.

If I have points `//XML/LEVEL1C/LEVEL2CA/LEVEL3CAB` and `//XML/LEVEL1A/LEVEL2AA/LEVEL3AAA` to a node tree, then I have to receive:

```
<XML>
    <LEVEL1A>
        <LEVEL2AA>
            <LEVEL3AAA>Some textAAA</LEVEL3AAA>
        </LEVEL2AA>
    </LEVEL1A>
    <LEVEL1C>
        <LEVEL2CA>
            <LEVEL3CAB>Some textCAB</LEVEL3CAB>
        </LEVEL2CA>
    </LEVEL1C>
</XML>
```

Is there a way to do it?

UPD:
I have for-each loop, where at end I return `<xsl:copy-of select="$output-node"/>` it's a part of named template, where $output-node is `<xsl:with-param name="output-node" select="//XML/LEVEL1A/LEVEL2CA/LEVEL3CAB"/>` when this named template called.

But now I need to not just print that node, but print that node and shortest XML subtree with that node.

UPD2:
Here is xslt example to parse it:

```
<xsl:template name="printme">
    <xsl:param name="output-node"/>
                <CURRENT_NODE>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$output-node"/>
                </CURRENT_NODE>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:for-each select="//XML">

    <xsl:if test="//current()/text() = 'Some textCAB'">

        <xsl:call-template name="comparefunc">
            <xsl:with-param name="output-node" select="//current()"/> 
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </xsl:if>    
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now I need incide `CURRENT_NODE` not just `<LEVEL3CAB>Some textCAB</LEVEL3CAB>`, but whole:

```
<CURRENT_NODE>
    <XML>
        <LEVEL1C>
            <LEVEL2CA>
                <LEVEL3CAB>Some textCAB</LEVEL3CAB>
            </LEVEL2CA>
        </LEVEL1C>
    </XML>
</CURRENT_NODE>
```

Comment: How will the stylesheet know which nodes you are interested in?

Comment: By XPath string "//XML/LEVEL1A/LEVEL2AA/LEVEL3AAA"

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't answer my question. Where will this string (or strings) be?  Note also that a string is not XPath (i.e. a node reference). It's not at all easy to turn a string into a node-set.

Comment: I updated post describing how I do and what I want :-)

Comment: Sorry, that's still not clear. I suggest you post some code that would allow us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Fixed it again :-) It is hard for me to put here real XML and real XSLT, because they use local literals in names.

Comment: It doesn't have to be real. Let me just see if I understand this correctly: you have some **test** to apply to the nodes (such as containing a given value), and you want to leave only nodes that passed this test and their ancestors (while retaining the original structure) - is that correct?

Comment: Similar. I have big XML with financial statements, and have to check it is correctly filled. So, I have a lot of checks, and if any check fails, I need to report about place where there was mistake. So, if XML has no mistakes then XSLT generates no output, but if it has some, I have to show place where mistake was done. Size of original XML may be up to 50Mb, so, I have to show just tags with broken info. But show long path to them, to let operator find that place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, let me adjust your input example to:

```
<XML>
    <LEVEL1A>
        <LEVEL2AA>
            <LEVEL3AAA>error</LEVEL3AAA>
        </LEVEL2AA>
        <LEVEL2AB>ok</LEVEL2AB>
    </LEVEL1A>
    <LEVEL1B>
        <LEVEL2BA>ok</LEVEL2BA>
    </LEVEL1B>
    <LEVEL1C>
        <LEVEL2CA>
            <LEVEL3CAA>ok</LEVEL3CAA>
            <LEVEL3CAB>error</LEVEL3CAB>
        </LEVEL2CA>
        <LEVEL2CB>ok</LEVEL2CB>
        <LEVEL2CC>ok</LEVEL2CC>
    </LEVEL1C>
</XML>
```

In this example, we'll be interested in elements that contain the text "error". The first step will create a variable containing a node-set of all elements that pass this test. Then we'll go over the entire tree and leave only these elements and their ancestors:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<!-- 1. identify nodes of interest  -->
<xsl:variable name="errors" select="//*[.='error']" />

<!-- 2. traverse the entire tree, leaving only nodes of interest and their ancestors -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="descendant::*[count(.|$errors) = count($errors)]">
        <!-- at least one of the descendants is a member of $errors -->
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="count(.|$errors) = count($errors)">
        <!-- this element is a member of $errors -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to our example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
   <LEVEL1A>
      <LEVEL2AA>
         <LEVEL3AAA>error</LEVEL3AAA>
      </LEVEL2AA>
   </LEVEL1A>
   <LEVEL1C>
      <LEVEL2CA>
         <LEVEL3CAB>error</LEVEL3CAB>
      </LEVEL2CA>
   </LEVEL1C>
</XML>
```

Comment: It works with your example. It still works if I create named template function with 'xsl:choose' and put there '$errors' as parameter. But as only I try to put 'xsl:choose' inside tags, such as 'CURRENT_NODE' from my example, it stops to work. Maybe I should put it somehow to variable and then call 'xsl:copy-of' with that variable?

Comment: @Arkady You must have a **node-set** of the elements of interest. *Node-set* is a data type in XSLT. I cannot follow your description, but it seems like you have a *result-tree-fragment* (another data type). If I am correct, you need to use the EXSLT exsl:node-set() extension function to convert the RTF to a node-set.